# Error in if (num < 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, if-statement, boolean, na, missing-data

```
y <- as.integer(readline(prompt ="Enter a number: "))
factorial = 1
 if (y< 0){
    print("Error")
 } else if (y== 0) 
 {
     print("1")
 } else
 { 
     for(i in 1:y)  {
            factorial = factorial * i
                    }
      return(factorial)
  }
```

wondering why this is giving:

> Error in if (y< 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

is it cause the first line has data type `NA_integer`?

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. What do you set `y` to?

Comment: You don't define a function so you don't need to return anything, try changing `return(factorial)` to `factorial`

Comment: @zack that doesn't appear to be causing the error in `if` statement.

Comment: @Roman it was for me when I entered a value that caused it to actually evaluate that line: `Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level`. 

@seun - be sure `y` is not `NA` when you run this code, that would fail to give you `TRUE` or `FALSE` value if you ran the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

There are three possible ways to pass values to the `if` statement.

```
y <- 1
if (y > 0) print("more")
```

This one works as expected.

```
y <- 1:3
if (y > 0) print("ignores all but 1st element")
```

As the warning message will tell you, only the first element was used to evaluate it. You could use `any` or `all` to make this right.

```
y <- NA
if (y > 0) print("your error")
```

This case actually gives you your error. I would wager a bet that `y` is somehow `NA`. You will probably need to provide a reproducible example (with data and the whole shebang) if you'll want more assistance. Note also that it helps visually structure your code to improve readability.

Comment: That's a good bet. `as.integer` converts non-digit character vectors to NA